# Clickonce application not downloading audio files nor folders

Tags: c#, clickonce, windows-forms-core

So in my app (windows forms) I have a sounds folder which contains a bunch of audio files the app uses. All the files are set to "copy always" and "include in project". But when I install the app via clickonce it does not have neither the folder or the audio files. Is there any fix or is this a clickonce limitation?
When I build a release of the app and run it, it does generate those files and the folder.

Comment: Use mage to edit the manifest to include the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup only uses the files whose "Build Action" is "Resource". Make sure you have assigned your files as "Resource".